# how to acees asp.net button or controls in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I access ASP.Net buttons or controls using jQuery in the following example?

```
window.onload = body_load;
function body_load() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btn.ClientID %>');
}

$("#btn").click(function () {
}

<asp:Button ID="btn" Width="134px" runat="server" Text="Fix" CssClass="cssbutton" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind event with asp.net button using jquery on document ready like this.

```
$(function(){

    $('#<%=btn.ClientID %>').click(function() {

      alert("clicked");
      return false; // returning false will stop from postback to server, true will cause postback

    });

});
```

Comment: i ahve to load in function body_load()
  {} then use

Comment: I have updated my answer now it will bind the click on load of page

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
$("#<%= btn.ClientID %>").click(function () {
});
```